# cost-sensitive multi-label classification using mlr package

Tags: r, multilabel-classification, mlr

Is there a way to perform a cost-sensitive *multi-label* classification with *example-dependent* costs using the `mlr` package?

(not *class-dependent* costs! see: [mlr tutorial](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/cost_sensitive_classif.html))

It seems to me the according `Task()` should somehow be a combination of `makeMultilabelTask()` and `makeCostSensTask()`

I think it would be sufficient to pass a label-specific weight vector from the cost matrix to each of the (e.g. Binary Relevance) classifiers, right?

Is there already an elegant way to do this with `mlr`?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, this is currently not supported in mlr. You could probably do it yourself though e.g. by doing multi-label classification through a series of individual classifiers.

Comment: I could also combine mlrCPO with the multi-label wrapper, right? I think it could be used to pass a label-specific weight vector to the binary relevance classifiers. I have to try this out.